# Skipping function parameters

Tags: php

If I have a function defined like this:

```
function x($a, $b, $c)
```

How can I make a call like `query('a', 'b')`, with b replaced by $c?

Comment: `x('a', null, 'c')`, perhaps?

Comment: please read the fine manual

Answer (score 2):

You can call it with `query('a', null, 'b')`

Comment: It will be really hard to track and maintain. What if I add $d in the future? All references has to be cleaned up.

Comment: if you add `$d` in the future, it's not a problem as long as you assign it a default value in the function declaration, like `function x($a, $b, $c, $d = null)`. Then you can still call function with only the first three arguments